# Getting No Linked You Tube account while implementing the API

Tags: php, authsub

I have been trying to upload video to you tube using AuthSub.I cant use Zend here so the client library is out of the question.I am following following steps:

1.Redirecting the user to the authorization page.
2.Getting the token from the redirection.
3.Getting the AuthSubSession token from https://www.google.com/accounts/AuthSubSessionToken which i successfully extracted.
4.Using the token from the step 3 to upload metadata of videos to the site through url ttp://gdata.youtube.com/action/GetUploadToken after which i will get the URL to upload the video.

The problem is on calling http://gdata.youtube.com/action/GetUploadToken i get a NoLinkedYoutube account error.
I tried creating a fresh account as well,But to no avail.Can any one figure out what i am doing wrong here?Please help me i only have this week to solve this.

Regards
Himanshu Sharma